# How to trick windows store that you have more than 1GB of RAM

Tags: windows, windows-10, memory, windows-store, tablet-pc

So I came across an old tablet with windows 8.1, installed windows 10 successfully on it, it is smooth and fast sometimes sluggish when it has like few tabs on chrome, the problem now is that I CAN NOT install Instagram, facebook, and messenger from the store as they require 2GB of RAM, I know from fact that these apps don't really need that much of RAM but I don't know how I can  spoof this or sideload the apps from another source maybe.
NOTE:I don't want to buy a new tablet I want to challenge you ( and myself) of finding a way to spoof windows store that I have 2 GB of RAM and install these apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method works as of January 2019 (don't know about the future)
So I was able to install the apps (Note:My tablet has 1GB of dd3 RAM) successfully using software called fiddler 4 and another laptop, using this method I just got the appx file downloaded and installed the appx on my tablet(double tap the appx file and it will prompt you to install), hope it helps to someone with a similar problem or request.
I installed with success:
1)Instagram works smoothly.
2)Facebook works ok sometimes it lags when scrolling.
3)Messenger works smoothly without lag.
Another NOTE: To download the appx file just paste the URL address found by fiddler4 on a browser and wait few minutes to download (it will say waiting for a request and it won't load any webpage don't worry it will be downloaded).